# Load test result interpretation

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing

In visual studio I've got results of load test, and little bit confused with how total percentage of passed tests is calculated. Consider following example

### |Test__  | Count | Passed  |

### |Test 1      |10_____| 10____|

### |Test 2 |50_____|50____|

### |Test 3|40_____|40____|

### |Test 4| 1_____|_0____|

What will be the result of total passed test? 75% or 0.99%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load testing is about running a small number of test cases many times each. One, or a small number, of executions of an individual test case do not mean that that test has failed. For the numbers in your question you have: 101 tests executed. 100 tests passed. 1 test failed. Hence (100/101)*100% passing.